# CSS animation performance issues using SVG drop-shadow filter

Tags: performance, css, animation, svg

I have this;

http://codepen.io/tacrossman/pen/JDxcf

Which is working fine without this part of the CSS (line 78);

```
svg {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 1px 1px 5px #000 );
}
```

But when it is there is has significant performance issues (jerkiness) with the animation on the :hover state of the tile.

Is this a known issue with performance or am I applying the drop-shadow incorrectly? I have tried to place it on each SVG specifically but to no avail too.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: I think you've hit a magic spot of poor performance. If I were doing this, I'd try doing it in pure SVG + JavaScript within a single SVG container.

Answer (score 0):

Drop shadow is just a very expensive filter inherently. Use box-shadow or an image, so that the pixels for the shadow are only drawn once.